# how to id as key in mysql select return

Tags: mysql

I need return of my mysql query

from

```sql
SELECT name as id FROM table
```

but I need return like this in mysql (I wrote it in an array because it's easy to write)

```php
[
  20: 'Jack',//20 is id from table and Jack is name from table
  40: 'Nano',
  49: 'Hakase'
]
```

Comment: json encode the result in php/js or whatever language you using

Comment: I think you want `SELECT id, name FROM table` (note `,`, not `=`)

Comment: *"json encode the result in php/js or whatever language you using "* @unreleased not needed. MySQL has native [JSON generating functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-creation-functions.html)

Comment: What format even is that result?  It's not a valid JSON array structure.

Comment: *"What format even is that result? It's not a valid JSON array structure"* indeed @David most likely it's a PHP array format.. topicstarter i advice you to read [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query) for providing example data and expected results

Comment: no no, what I need is if the results of mysql are exported in an array, the id of the row will be the key in the array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, select all id and name using

```
SELECT id, name FROM table SOME CONDITIONS
```

this query would return a result like

```
$result = [
  [ id => 1, name => 'name' ],
  [ id => 1, name => 'name' ],
  [ id => 1, name => 'name' ],
  [ id => 1, name => 'name' ],
]
```

then arrange array

```
$accepted_output = array_column($result, 'id', 'name')

$accepted_output  = [
  [ 1 =>  'name' ],
  [ 1 =>  'name' ],
  [ 1 =>  'name' ],
  [ 1 =>  'name' ],
]
```

array_column docs - https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php

Answer (score 1):

Use `WHERE` condition

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE ID = yourId`

just replace `yourId` for the ID number you want.

Comment: IS it what OP wanted?

Comment: no no, what I need is if the results of mysql are exported in an array, the id of the row will be the key in the array

Answer (score 0):

You want to return the ID and the name so you should rewrite your query to:

```
SELECT id,name FROM table
```

You should use commas to seperate field names.

For more information you can do some reading [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html).

Comment: no no, what I need is if the results of mysql are exported in an array, the id of the row will be the key in the array

Comment: @jackwilliams What do you mean 'an array'? What language are you doing this on?